# Embeded entity as collection in form symfony2

Tags: symfony

I have a table of users
`id|email|... 
1|example@example.com`
table 'favorite' of dynamic field fo user
`id|name
1|juice
2|book
etc`
and 3 table 'favorite_user' to store the parameters of table 2
`id|user|field|note
  1|   1|    1|orage
  2|   1|    2|classic`
Form must be created that contains all the fields from 2 tables and the input field 'note' of the 3 tables for each value of 2 table, but by doing it through formbilder collection of entity does not display anything
Code form for favorite_user:

```
$builder
            ->add('favorite', 'collection',
                    array(
                'type' => 'Acme\DemoBundle\Form\Type\FavoriteFormType',
            ))
            ->add('note')
            ->add('button', 'submit');
```

Code for favorite

```
$builder
            ->add('favorite', 'entity',
                    array(
                'class' => 'Acme\DemoBundle\Entity\Favorite',
                'property' => 'name'
    ));
```

This shows

```
<div id="favoriteUser" class="form-control"></div>
```

But need input for juice, input for book. How to do it?

Answer (score 0):

```
  $builder
        ->add('favorite', 'collection', array(
            'type' => //you have to specify the favorite form type here not an entity,
        ))
```

check the doc: http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/collection.html#type

and this is exactly what you are trying to achieve: http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/form_collections.html

Comment: sorry, typo, there used FormType

Comment: and [http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/form_collections.html](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/form_collections.html) this guide how add a new record, but i need choise all records from DB, and display them as Favorite.name -> label, favorite_user.note -> input